# Starting Tomcat 8 with Cargo in background

Tags: maven, background-process, tomcat8, spawn, cargo-maven2-plugin

I'm trying to run a web application using Cargo and Tomcat 8 (installed mode). I would start Tomcat as a background process with maven (by default, cargo:run blocks the console, waiting for a Ctrl+C), so I set `cargo.process.spawn` property to `true`, but I get the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building webapp-launcher 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.2:run (default-cli) @ webapp-launcher ---
[INFO] [en2.ContainerRunMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.6.2 for container tomcat8x
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x starting...
[INFO] [stalledLocalDeployer] Deploying [/home/tomcat/.m2/repository/<<****removed****>>/<<****removed****>>.war] to [/home/tomcat/<<****removed****>>/target/cargo/configurations/tomcat8x/webapps]...
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Tomcat 8.x started on port [8080]
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] spawn does not allow attributes related to input, output, error, result
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] spawn also does not allow timeout
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] finally, spawn is not compatible with a nested I/O <redirector>
[INFO] Press Ctrl-C to stop the container...
```

I tried to set `timeout` to `0`, but nothing changed.

This is the pom.xml I'm using to deploy the webapp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>dummy.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>webapp-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots-1</id>
            <name>Snaphots</name>
            <url>***********************removed***********************</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases-1</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>***********************removed***********************</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>***********************removed***********************</groupId>
            <artifactId>***********************removed***********************</artifactId>
            <version>***********************removed***********************</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <timeout>0</timeout>
                        <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                        <artifactInstaller>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
                            <version>8.5.12</version>
                        </artifactInstaller>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>standalone</type>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.process.spawn>true</cargo.process.spawn>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>***********************removed***********************</groupId>
                            <artifactId>***********************removed***********************</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT:**

I think it's a bug, since the `org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.jvm.DefaultJvmLauncherFactory` class sets a lot of hardcoded parameters that are not compatible with spawn mode (see [this](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/master/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Java.java#L167) line).

Comment: Looks like a bug. Can you please report this to [Cargo JIRA](https://codehaus-cargo.atlassian.net/projects/CARGO/issues) ?

Comment: Issue filed. See [here](https://codehaus-cargo.atlassian.net/browse/CARGO-1433)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fixed in Cargo version 1.6.3.